# Will my ghusl will be accepted by doing it from sink by using wet hands?

Tags: ghusl

So I did ghusl in the sink by washing my hands three times and then washing private part and then again washed hands and the I washed my head/hair from sink and then washed the whole body with wet hands. My main concern is if I washed my body by wet hands will my ghusl gets accepted?